# How to parse the transcript from tedtalks

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

can't parse the transcript of a video from https://www.ted.com/talks/alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging/transcript

the requests won't see the span class where the text actually is. What could be the problem?

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ted.com/talks/alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging/transcript'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.content)
```

Is there any way to reach the transcript? Thank you.
[I need to reach this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeo46.png)
[no atrribute found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGGlo.png)

Comment: I suspect, without digging too much, that a lot of the content is loaded by javascript or additional calls for content, so you'll probably need to do some more scraping than making a basic get request for the page.

Comment: @theherk you're right, they retrieve the data from their GraphQL endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the data is not loaded via the link you're using, but via a call to their GraphQL instance.

Using curl, you can fetch the data like so:

```bash
curl 'https://www.ted.com/graphql?operationName=Transcript&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%2218f8e983b84c734317ae9388c83a13bc98702921b141c2124b3ce4aeb6c48ef6%22%7D%7D' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Referer: https://www.ted.com/talks/alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging/transcript' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'client-id: Zenith production' -H 'x-operation-name: Transcript' --output - | gzip -d
```

Note, the URL is urlencoded. You can import `from urllib.parse import quote` to use the `quote()` method to urlencode a string in python.

So simply translate the above curl command to python.
There's no magic, simply set the correct headers.
If you're lazy, you can also use [this](https://reqbin.com/req/python/c-xgafmluu/convert-curl-to-python-requests) online converter, to convert a curl command to python code.

This produces:

```py
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://www.ted.com/graphql?operationName=Transcript&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%2218f8e983b84c734317ae9388c83a13bc98702921b141c2124b3ce4aeb6c48ef6%22%7D%7D"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
headers["Accept"] = "*/*"
headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br"
headers["Referer"] = "https://www.ted.com/talks/alexis_nikole_nelson_a_flavorful_field_guide_to_foraging/transcript"
headers["content-type"] = "application/json"
headers["client-id"] = "Zenith production"
headers["x-operation-name"] = "Transcript"

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp.content)
```

Output:

```py
b'{"data":{"translation":{"id":"209255","language" ...
```

Comment: it's so helpful! Thank you!

Comment: well i gave up to find out how the curled string appeared, probably the task is too hard for the beginner)) I parsed the text from the link I provided with the help of your code, but can't get it how to make this   "https://www.ted.com/graphql?operationName=Transcript&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%........" from the other link

Comment: I guess the problem is the hash, they provide in the URL. If we don't know, what exactly was hashed, you cannot adapt the URL for any other talk, but have to find out the exact URL from your dev tools in your browser (as I did for my response).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will continue working on it